# How do i make a bootstrap form in django scrollable?

Tags: django, django-forms, backend, bootstrap-form-helper

[image]

I have tried different CSS properties to make the form scrollable but none is working.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Instead of adding the image of code paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"> #CDN added here
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script> #CDN added here
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script> #CDN added here
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> #CDN added here
</head>
<body>

<div  data-spy="scroll" class="container"> #Added here
  <h2>Form</h2>
 
  <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd">
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <br />
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br /><br />
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email"><br /><br />
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label><br /><br />
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd"><br /><br />
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div><br /><br />
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Just add like below tag:

#Updated here

```
<div data-spy="scroll" data-target=".nav"> #.nav is classname from navbar
  <form>
     #Add here your form
  </form>
</div>
```

The form must be inside div tag and now form is scrollable.

And now your problem is solved.

Happy coding!

Comment: The problem still persist after adding the "data-spy=scroll" properties.

Comment: where you added that

Comment: But in my answer form is scrolling

Comment: I added it inside the div housing the form

Comment: Is form scrolling now?

Comment: try to add inside form tag also  <form "data-spy=scroll"></form>

Comment: No, i added into the form tag as well and its still not scrolling.

Comment: have you added correct cdn link? If not then cdn link is available in my answer

Comment: i have added the correct cdn link and its still the same. #Sobs. Please note that the form page is inheriting its Nav properties from a different html page entirely

Comment: Updated my div tag checkout

Comment: last thing, try to add that in body tag